# how to find the location within image using latitude and longitude of the location that store in spatial image?

Tags: spatial

Take location that user enter at the time of registration and provide
only that image of location with crop image.
For example, there is satellite images of 'gujarat' (TIFF image-Spatial
Image) store in spatial database. now user want to access only ahmedabad, he/she enter Ahmedabad then access only ahmedabad portion from the whole gujarat image instead of whole image display.

Comment: please provide some code what u have tried so far.

Comment: You must also indicate that database, that server images and language that you are working